# How to troubleshoot intermittently slow queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a query which most of the time takes about 150ms to complete.  Thousands go through the system each day without any issue.  But every few days, something happens, and one of these queries suddenly takes roughly 30 minutes to complete.  Any subsequent queries also run slow.  The only way we have been able to recover is to kill ever single one of these queries.  Soon as we do that, any subsequent queries again run at usual 150ms speed.  For security reasons, I am not allowed to post the query itself.  But it is nothing special.

The dB is MySQL 5.5.40 and using the innodb engine.  During this period, all the usual system resources look fine - memory, cpu, disk space, disk i/o, network i/o.

Can someone give me some ideas about how I can troubleshoot the nature of this issue?  I do not believe it is the query, since it seems to work just great 99% of the time.  So I am thinking there is some kind of MySQL bug or a weird race condition going on.

Comment: Oh, another piece of information, the processlist show the number of examines rows ever increasing and a few orders of magnitude larger than when the query runs at normal speed.  The innodb engine status does not show any deadlocks either.

Comment: More data - there is a where-in-subquery.  The subquery runs super fast.  If I replace the subquery with it's output, the full query runs super fast.  But with both, super slow...  WTF?  Isn't that basically how it works?  Any subquery is replaced with it's output and the outer query is then evaluated?

Comment: With the few details you are able to give, it is very hard to guess what is going on. Did you make an _explain extended ...; show warnings;_ ? From what you are writing, your subquery seems very _costy_ to calculate.

Comment: The subquery by itself only takes 100 msec.  The explain doesn't show anything useful.  Nor does it change from when the dB is being fast, versus when it is being slow.  Like I said, I really don't think it's the query itself.  Otherwise, why would it suddenly, after several days, get 4 orders of magnitude slower, and then fast again, soon as I kill those queries.

Comment: Is your DB in a virtualized environment or does it run on a physical server? I once had the phenomenon from within a virtualized environment everything seemed okay, but the physical disks underneath were spinning like crazy, since it had several VMs running with some DBs. So other VMs disturbed this one.

Comment: What version are you using?  `IN(SELECT...)` performs poorly; turn it into a JOIN.  Let's see the query and the EXPLAIN and SHOW CREATE TABLE.  Is the Query cache turned on?  How many rows are returned?  If you run the query twice in rapid succession, is it always fast the second time?  There are hundreds of possible issues; I don't want to go through a long list.

Comment: The dB is on a dedicated physical server.  So no weird VM shared resource issues involved.  We did make a flat version of the query using only joins.  Because the subquery returns quite a few results, when the dB is behaving, it is much faster, by 20x.  But the flat version does not seem to be impacted by whatever this issue is, so when the dB is misbehaving, the flat version only gets a little slower, but does not hang up.  We deployed the flat version until we upgrade to 5.6.  Then we will revert the change to see if this is all some weird dB planner bug or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been some kind of issue with the planner in MySQL 5.5.  Since our upgrade to 5.6, the problem has gone away.  Also the explain of the query is completely different.